# How to Read a text file after skipping specified number of lines in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, text-files, skip

I have a text file which i do need to read line by line.Now as per my requirement i have to read text file after **65** lines.for this i am trying to use skip() but its not working ..Here is my code ..

```
string FileToCopy = "D:\\tickets.txt";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) == true)
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(FileToCopy, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                string line;
                string rawcdr="";
                while (true)
                {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()).Skip(65) != null)
                    {
                        if (line != "")
                        {
                            rawcdr = line.ToString();
                        }
                        var strings = rawcdr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        if (strings.Length != 0)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

On executig above code.Text file is being read from first line whereas i do need to read from **66** line..Where am i going wrong?

Comment: ..because `(line = reader.ReadLine())`.. evaluates to a string. You're skipping 65 characters. Also, `while(true)` with no break would lock this up..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead how to achieve skipping 65 lines from text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\tickets.txt")
                .Skip(65);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
   // do what you want with other lines...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [Enumerable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may work for you

```
var listOfOtherLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(65).ToList();
```